# Where do the rate laws for the Chlorine Dioxide-Iodine-Malonic Acid reaction come from?

Tags: redox, kinetics

After reading a section on this particular oscillatory reaction, something started bugging me about it.

However, let me lay out the basis of my question.  From what I've researched, Lengyel and Epstein proposed a model that captures the overall behavior of the system. There are a few different versions of the model in regard to the dimensions, but this seems to be the most popular:

$\ce{MA+I_2 \rightarrow IMA + I^- + H^+;\hspace{1mm} \frac{d[I_2]}{dt} = -\frac{k_{1a}[MA][I_2]}{k_{1b}+[I_2]}}$

$\ce{ClO_2 + I^2 \rightarrow ClO_2^+ + \frac{1}{2}I_2; \hspace{1mm}\frac{d[CLO_2]}{dt} = -k_2[CLO_2][I^-]}$

$\ce{ClO_2^- + 4I^- + 4H^+ \rightarrow Cl^- + 2I_2 + 2H_2O}$

$\ce{\frac{d[CLO_2^-]}{dt} = -k_{3a}[ClO_2^-][I^-][H^+]-k_{3b}[CLO_2^-][I_2]\frac{[I^-]}{u+[I^-]^2}}$

Personally, I am much more familiar with the mathematics than the chemistry.  **First, are these rate laws empirical or were they derived from physical laws?** Pardon me if this is a naive question, but I am not as familiar with chemistry than the other hard sciences. In basic cases, rate laws are a straight multiplication of the concentrations of the present species. However, that neglects situations involving, for example, autocatalycity.  My suspicion is that it is a mixture of processes that I'm not familiar with and simple observation.

Obviously, these reactions don't violate the laws of thermodynamics. **My assumption is that the overall free energy of the system continues to decline - meaning that the system eventually reaches equilibrium.  Unfortunately, I've been at a loss to find good sources on oscillatory chemical reactions.**

Comment: From what I know the rate law of a reaction can only be determined experimentally. I'm not sure if there are any exceptions.

Comment: @kaliaden You raise a good point. Rate laws can only be determined experimentally.  What I should have said is that the general framework of rate laws may be determined before experiments. For instance, A+B->C (assuming an elementary step) rate law has the general form of r=k[A]^a[B]^b. "k" can only be determined by experiment - thus forming the full rate law. That said, my question is really if a general framework was developed empirically, or there is a an principle forming a basis for the development of the rate laws in my post.

Comment: I do not understand what Your question is. Do You know it Yourself?

Comment: @Georg "First, are these rate laws empirical or were they derived from physical laws?" And second: how is the reaction described thermodynamically? (the last paragraph).